# Play Scala Form Helper with custom HTML

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I'm creating a form in Play using the following code:

```
@inputText(loginForm("password"),
                        'type -> "password",
                        '_label -> null)
```

It generates the following HTML code:

```
<dl class=" " id="password_field">
<dt><label for="password"></label></dt>
<dd>
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="">
```

While I want it to generate:

```
<input type="password" id="password" name="password" value="">
```

Is there an easy way of doing this?

Comment: related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16606042/scala-template-apply-style-to-inputtexts-label-play-2-html5-helper-tag

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve this by creating a custom FieldConstructor (see http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.3.x/ScalaCustomFieldConstructors).

Create a new file `views/helper/myPlainFieldConstructor.scala.html` that contains the following:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)

@elements.input
```

[For reference, you can see the default field constructor [here](https://github.com/playframework/playframework/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/views/helper/defaultFieldConstructor.scala.html).]

Then, in the view template containing your form:

```
@import helper._
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myPlainFieldConstructor.f) }

[...]

@form(action = ...) {
  @inputPassword(loginForm("password"))
}
```

Note: If you really need `value=""`, you can add `'value -> ""` to the helper's arguments, i.e.

```
@inputPassword(loginForm("password"), 'value -> "")
```

Or further customize the HTML with the generic `input` helper, as in:

```
@input(loginForm("password")) { (id, name, value, args) =>
    <input type="password" name="@name" id="@id" value="" @toHtmlArgs(args)>
}
```