# Form doesnt work when adding attributes to ScalaFormHelpers

Tags: forms, scala, playframework

My form doesn't seem to work when I add attributes to my form, this is how the form looks like right now(this code doesn't work):

`advPlaatsen.scala.html`

```
@import helper._
@implicitField = @{ FieldConstructor(myPlainFieldConstructor.f) }
@form(routes.Application.newAdv, 'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
<div class="row collapse">
    <div class="small-2 columns">
            <span class="prefix">Jaar</span>
    </div>
    <div class="small-4 left columns">
            @inputText(advForm("Jaar"),
            'id -> "right-label",
            'placeholder -> "Jaar",
            'name ->"jaar")
    </div>
    </div>
<input type="submit" value="Create">
}
```

`myPlainFieldConstructor.html.scala`:

```
@(elements: helper.FieldElements)
@elements.input
```

I'm using a total of 6 input types, five of them are text and one is a file input, they seem to be working perfectly when it the default helper:

```
@inputText(advForm("Jaar"))
```

If you need any more of my code please let me know,

I used this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24728377/play-scala-form-helper-with-custom-html?lq=1) on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your custom FieldConstructor is a scala file, not a scala template.

Change

```
myPlainFieldConstructor.html.scala
```

To

```
myPlainFieldConstructor.scala.html
```